# Why using getComponent to call objects in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new in unity, I'm just wondering why we call the player object like this :

```c
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        // if the player hit the enemy then destroy the ememy
        if (other.tag == "PLAYER" ) {
            // like this
            other.transform.GetComponent<Player>().damage();  
        }
```

while we can make the `damege` method `static` and call it like this :

```c
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        // if the player hit the enemy then destroy the ememy
        if (other.tag == "PLAYER" ) {
            //other.transform.GetComponent<Player>().damage();
            Player.damage(); 
        }
```

why we call the object like this what the point

```
other.transform.GetComponent<Player>().damage();
```

does it effect performance ? or is it just another available way to call objects

Comment: If you want to damage a specific player instance, you need to use an instance method.

Comment: I suggest reading up on this, because it is very important to know the differences so you can determine which one to use for a given scenario.  [Method Invocation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/methods#method-invocation)

Comment: thx a lot @hijinxbassist it's a very useful reference that u gave me

Comment: because using `static` here is extremely bad practice and string couples your classes together .. what if later on you have multiple players .. or e.g. also enemy objects that should get hit by the same object .. in general you would rather have an interface `IDamageable { void Damage(); }` and use that instead.. then you also wouldn't need the tag at all .. you can rather simply check for `if(other.TryGetComponent<IDamageable>(out var damageable)) damageable.Damage();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to explain this the best I can. This explanation isn't perfect, but I worded it so it makes the most sense.
A class is a file that contains code. There are two "types" of classes, static and non-static. Static classes can be accessed anywhere, but there is only ever 1 copy. For example, use UnityEngine.Mathf. That is a static class, so you can just do Mathf.(whatever).

The non-static class can have multiple copies. Non-static classes can have static methods and fields, which can be accessed like you would a static class. For most basic applications, these classes just use normal methods. These methods are instance-dependent.

For example, take a non-static Player class.

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour {
    //This is accessed using Player.instance
    public static Player instance;
    //This function only runs on the script you place on a GameObject
    public void Start(){
        //Sets the static instance to this instance
        instance = this;
    }
}
```

You can then access the active player instance with any other script (as long as the instance variable was set before)

```
public Player GetPlayer() {
    //As you can see, you don't need a reference to a Player; you can just use the static instance.
    Player instance = Player.instance;
    return instance;
}
```

In conclusion, using Player.Whatever references the static version. Using playerInstance.Whatever references a runtime instance. If you will only have one runtime instance of a class, you can use the example above to allow other classes to access the instance.